# SonarQube warning about NPE even though null check is done

Tags: nullpointerexception, sonarqube

Why does Sq keep saying that the lines:

```
bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setOrderReference(authResponse.getBody().getOrderRef());
                    bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setAutoStartToken(authResponse.getBody().getAutoStartToken());
```

Can cause a NPE even after i check for it?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that `authResponse.getBody().getOrderRef()` returns an `Integer` but `bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setOrderReference` takes an `int`, or similar? It's difficult to say without any further information. Also, IntelliJ (which you seem to be using) is highlighting `authResponse.getBody().getOrderRef`, which normally indicates it has found a problem with that bit of code. Are you using a SonarQube plugin for IntelliJ or is the IDE trying to give you a hint about what could be wrong?

Comment: Im ysing SQ plugin for intellij. Thats whats complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 cases:

1st case: If `getBody()` method may return different (including `null`) results on consecutive calls then it may cause NPE.

Try to extract the result of the first call into a variable like this:

```
final BodyClass body = authResponse.getBody();
if(body != null) {
    bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setOrderReference(body.getOrderRef());
    bankIdAuthenticationEntity.setAutoStartToken(body.getAutoStartToken());
} else {
    // ...
}
```

2nd case is (mentioned in a comment by Luke Woodward) that both methods `getOrderRef()` and `getAutoStartToken()` may returned `Integer`/`Long`/`Character` which may be `null`.

Then they need to be unboxed into `int`/`long`/`char` by the `setOrderReference(...)` and `setAutoStartToken(...)` methods which may cause NPE.